# Assigning columns of data from a file to variables extracted from headers

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I'm very new to *Mathematica*.

I want import a file in which the first colum is a function f1, the second another function f2. So the file looks like this:

```
f1       f2
12       7
14       11
18       15
13       7
```

I try to import that file with:

```
Import["testfile.dat","Table"]
```

Now, however, I have one table in which are both functions! So I want to split that table in the function `f1` and `f2`. Maybe via a different method of importing?

So it my target is actually that it should look like this:

```
f1 = {12, 14, 18, 13}
f2 = {7, 11, 15, 7}
```

Comment: Look up `Transpose[]`.

Comment: `{f1,f2} = Transpose[data]` or `f1 = data[[All, 1]]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, those solutions also worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a text file with the following lines

```
f1       f2  
12       7  
14       11
18       15
13       7
```

saved it my desktop and then imported it with

```
data = Import[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "test.dat"}]]
```

To transform the imported data as requested, I evaluated

```
Clear[f1, f2]
Evaluate[Symbol /@ data[[1]]] = Transpose[Rest[data]];
{f1, f2}
```

> `{{12, 14, 18, 13}, {7, 11, 15, 7}}`

#### Update

As often happens with me, I have had second thoughts about the above code. It bothers me that the variables names are given explicitly in the code; they should be determined from the imported table. My revision is

```
With[{vars = First[data], vals = Rest[data]},
  Evaluate[Clear @@ vars; Symbol /@ vars] = Transpose[vals]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Is this perfomance wise also the best solution? Because I have to import 2 functions with 16000 samples each. This script runs on a raspberry pi in an endless loop.

Comment: @TheCheatsrichter. Best performance as compared to what other methods? I have done no performance testing on my code. I believe the  data transformation step will be faster than the import step. All the operations appearing in the transformation code are well-optimized built-in functions, so should be quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

I use `ImportString` as I don't have your file. Just swap it for your `Import`.

```
With[{\[FormalX] = Symbol@First@#},
   \[FormalX] = Rest@#] & /@ Transpose@
ImportString["f1       f2
   12       7
   14       11
   18       15
   13       7", "Table"]
```

Then

```
f1
(* {12, 14, 18, 13} *)

f2
(* {7, 11, 15, 7} *)
```

Hope this helps.